# should i use SingleTone or static?

Tags: android, performance, static, singleton

I want to clean my main class by split the creation of different views into other class .

i did it by create classes like SomeKindOfViewCreator and than put a static method that get context and return the view .

i usually used static method only for utils , my question is if this is the current way to go ? making class for each complex view i need to create with static method or i should use SingleTone class instead ? or even create new object every time i need to create the view ?

this methods can be called many times during the application life time , as a developer that knows we should not use static unless i know for sure it will be the right way to go i am asking my self is this the right solution for the situation i have describe  .

static ? single tone ? what is the downside in my case in static method if any ?

By the way , my code working fine with the static but that is not my point , i want to learn and to understand why i should or not do it this way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your understanding what a singelton pattern [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). And the way i know to do is described in [MVC-Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

So basically, devide your code into data classes, view classes and logic classes. So you can handle your views with the controller, then there is no need for singletons or any other static way. Beware of singeltons and static stuff, since two different calls can block each other ([deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)) and then you would need mutexes or [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29).